# Why doesn't this instance of this class's method take this argument?

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x, variables

My question is why I can't make a object of the class giving it an integer as an argument. It totally ignores the value that I pass as an argument to it. Yet, if I call the area function from the class and pass the same number into it's parentheses it will output the desired result of 144.

My best guess from what I have read so far is that the way the classes function is coded is incorrect for what I am hoping that it will achieve. Do I need to have the area function take it's argument like: `self.length` ?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class square:
    sides = 4
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def area(self, length):
        return length * length

box = square(12)
print(box.area())
```

Output: `TypeError: area() missing 1 required positional argument: 'length'`

Shouldn't the object that is created save the value that is given to it for the duration of that objects life? Why does it throw another error when I tell it to print from the area method a second time if the calls looked like this?

```
print(box.area(12))
output:144
print(box.area())
output: <bound method square_shape.area of <__main__.square_shape object at 0x7f5f88355b70>>
```

I'm sorry if this question is a little oddly phrased but I'm simply looking for as much information as I can get and attempting to gain a better understanding of what I'm doing here. Other questions on this subject didn't give a good grasp of what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are thinking of self.length. length (without a "self." in front of it) is just a local variable. If it's an argument, you need to provide it.

What you probably want is:

   `def area(self):
      return self.length * self.length`

Comment: So if I am understanding correctly, then length is a local variable to this object and the way I'm doing something is somehow treating it as a global variable?

Comment: Maybe? If you're thinking about it correctly then your current terminology is off. length is an instance field. There's also a length local variable. A "local variable" refers to the local scope which is the function itself. Once area finishes and returns a value, then "length" as a local variable is no longer defined. However self.length, the instance field maintains its value whenever you are dealing with this particular instance of this object.

Comment: You sir are a ingenious. Could you comment as to how the function taking self as an argument actually results in this witchcraft? When it is passes self, is it taking whatever arguments were passed at the objects creation to the area function?

Comment: It's more or less a convention to pass the "self" parameter in as the first argument of each class' method. The rest of the arguments are the so-called "real" arguments that you use when you call the function in other code. I'll also make a shout-out to the other answer to this question that words it differently than me which may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `area` takes the `self` argument, which is enough to access `self.length`:

```
...
def area(self):
  return self.length * self.length
```

Then you can call `square(3).area()` and get `9`.

Your current declaration requires an *explicit* length argument, something like `square(3).area(4)` which would produce `16`.

One of the key tenets of OOP is that *methods* have access to object's (or often said *instance's*) state, and can operate on that state, instead of passing it explicitly.

In Python, the parameter normally named `self` is used to pass the object in question to the method. The `area` method operates on `square`'s `length`; you access it as `self.length`. That `self` is an instance of `square`, the thing that e.g. `square(3)` returns.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to get the area length value from class parameter, you should do it, like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
class square:
    sides = 4
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def area(self):
        # create a new variable and set it to class length parameter
        length = self.length
        return length * length

box = square(12)
print(box.area())
```

Comment: try to reformat your codes using triple ` characters